# Can't install Laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The first error I had was `php` version wasn't up to date, so when I updated it, I receive this:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
    - Installation request for laravel/cashier ~6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v6.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
    - laravel/cashier v6.0.0 requires illuminate/database ~5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0].
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
```

Does anyone know what it means and how to fix it so cashier will install successfully?

Comment: what version of php do you have, what version of laravel are you on, etc ...

Comment: php version is PHP 5.6.16, Laravel is 5.0.34

Comment: fantastic, you may want to try the ~5.0 branch of cashier, seems 6.0  is using the 5.1 version of illuminate libs and not the 5.0 versions.

Comment: Ahh yea that did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having this issue on Laravel 5.0 you will probably want to make sure you grab the version of Cashier that is compatible.

Laravel Cashier `~5.0` should work with Laravel 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem although solved  by this way:

composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary